# Center pgf-tikz path

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I want the tips of my plot to be centered, instead of it being on the side.
I don't have any knowledge on graphics and `\centering` does not work.

Picture produced by code:

[image: Original]

Picture of I want it to be:

[image: Supposed]

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.75pt, x=0.75pt, yscale=-1, xscale=1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, <->]
\begin{scope}
\path[color=black,draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=4.00,even odd rule,line width=2.000pt] (0,0) .. controls (65,85) and (105,-15) .. (135,-45) .. controls (185,-95) and (255,-70) .. (290,-120) .. controls (325,-160) and (340,30) .. (385,-10) .. controls (420,-50) and (440,-35) .. (480,-45) .. controls (505,-50) and (530,-95) .. (530,-95);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by tips?

Comment: The picture is too wide for the paper. `\centering` will centre the picture, but you will not notice the difference much unless the picture is smaller than the page in width.

Comment: @cfr Arrowheads.

Comment: @cfr How do I adjust it?

Comment: What should the arrow tips be centred with respect to?

Comment: both ends of the page

Comment: TeX sees first thing as your picture so it indents your picture as a paragraph. Place `\noindent` before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your MWE, the problem seems to be a bad box (specifically an overfull \hbox, which means that the image is too wide to fit in the paragraph). Playing a little with the values for `x` and `y` in the `tikzpicture` options, I found out that value `0.61pt` works fine, but then the image is smaller. Similarlly, you can try manipulating the values of the fileds `xscale` and `yscale`.

Another solution: you can wrap the `tikzpucture` image in a `figure` environment and use the `\centering` command to center the image. Note that I changed the `x` and `y` values, because with `0.75pt` the bad box still persists. I use the package `lipsum` just to write text to see the alignments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.64pt, x=0.64pt, yscale=-1, xscale=1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, <->]
\begin{scope}
\path[color=black,draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=4.00,even odd rule,line width=2.000pt] (0,0) .. controls (65,85) and (105,-15) .. (135,-45) .. controls (185,-95) and (255,-70) .. (290,-120) .. controls (325,-160) and (340,30) .. (385,-10) .. controls (420,-50) and (440,-35) .. (480,-45) .. controls (505,-50) and (530,-95) .. (530,-95);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is function of `scope`? it seems that its use is surplus ...

Comment: I believe so. As I understand (and as the TikZ PGF manual explains), the `scope` environment is something like a "local group" of commands, that takes graphic options as an optional argument and applies them to everything inside the environment, but not to anything outside. Besides, any changes to the clipping area are local to the scope, meaning that if you use `\clip` inside a scope, the effect of clipping stays on the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image: adjusted picture]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,showframe}
\tikzset{>=stealth}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.5pt, x=0.5pt, yscale=-1, xscale=1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, <->]
  \path[draw=black, line join=round, line cap=round,miter limit=4, line width=2pt] (0,0) .. controls (65,85) and (105,-15) .. (135,-45) .. controls (185,-95) and (255,-70) .. (290,-120) .. controls (325,-160) and (340,30) .. (385,-10) .. controls (420,-50) and (440,-35) .. (480,-45) .. controls (505,-50) and (530,-95) .. (530,-95);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```